# Display MySQL data when linking to new page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script that connects to my database and returns results: name, and price, however, now I am trying to also create a link - that opens a new php page "more_info.php" and displays the correct description that corresponds to correct name.

I have been trying to accomplish this, but I haven't been able to get it working.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) //mysql_fetch_array bring back an object, in this case the $result of the mysql query and puts it into a variable $row
 {
  echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['name'] . "</td> <td align='center'> <input type='button' value='More Info'; onclick=\"window.location='?start=' . $row['name.description'] . ?more_info.php?';\"> </td>";
```

within the onclick, I want the new window to open up, and bring in the description that matches the name, into the more_info.php

I input that code, but obviously it isn't working. Does this look like i'm on the right path at all?

Comment: Why are there so many question marks in the window.location?  I think you want window.location=more_info.php?start=".$row['name.description']

Also - Would using a popup make more sense?

Comment: I have it all screwed up... :/

Comment: General format is: index.php?name=Aaron&lastname=Kreider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it like this.

```
echo '<table>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
 {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td align="center">' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td align="center">'; 
  echo '<input type="button" value="More Info" onclick="window.location=\'more_info.php?start=' . urlencode($row['description']) . ' \';" />';
  echo '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
 }
 echo '</table>';
```

and read it in more_info.php like:

> 

```
<?php

  $start = (!empty($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start'] : false);
  echo '<h1>Info about: ' . $start . '</h1>';

?>
```

Comment: thank you for answering. This is what I had originally. The new problem and what I was trying to ask is how to I populate the $row['description'] into more_info.php -- the description is the name of the column in my database. It needs to be displayed for the correct name that more info was clicked for.

Comment: Edited code sends description as parameter to more_info.php i add example to my answer.. just a sec..

Comment: that did work, but it dumped the description in the url, i'm assuming because of the urlencode? How would I actually get that to be displayed on the more_info.php page?

Comment: Ok, added some more.. now you have to learn some basics by self.. try googling "php read get parameters"..

Comment: I was able to read it in the more_info.php script. I've never done this before. Thank you. Last question if you don't mind. Does the description have to remain in the url?

Comment: Yes, $_GET command reads from url and $_POST reads without url, but for that you need to build form for each row. try googling.. really basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be:

```
window.location='more_info.php?start=' . $row['name.description']
```

an alternative to using JS triggers on buttons for navigation is you could also just use a link and css style it to look like a button `<a href="more_info.php?start=' . $row['name.description'].'" class="button">`